# Python time.sleep() issue

Tags: python

I make with a function that I should trigger once a day at a certain time in it's own thread. I've go a code like this:

```
def reports_pending_morning():
    con = sqlite3.connect('sensor.db')
    # Here I import a time from string REPORT_TIME_1 constant like "10:00"
    t_report_1 = dt.datetime.strptime(REPORT_TIME_1, "%H:%M").time()
    while True:
        dt_current = dt.datetime.now().time()
        current = dt.time(dt_current.hour, dt_current.minute)
        if current == t_report_1:
            logger.info(' It s time to send data')
            # Here I've got a function to call
            send_data(con=con, schedule=True)
            time.sleep(60)
        time.sleep(1)
```

And in the main thread:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=reports_pending_morning, daemon=True,
                     name='scheduler thread').start()
... some other code...
```

So, it works perfectly most of the time. But if I run this scripts for a couple of days, the `current == dt.time(dt_current.hour, dt_current.minute)` conditions never reaches and the function `send_data()` never triggers. Why and how to fix?

Comment: Are you sure the program is still running without interruptions? What hardware and OS is this on?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 4. It's mounted to a kind of equipment and puts some data in db. Once a day it should send reports. And, althought the code is as simple as it possible, sometimes the funtion just do not gets triggered. No message in logs ('It s time to send data'), nothing. On my PC it works fine, so that's why I stuck :)